# java.io.FileInputStream.getChannel() Method

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream

I'm working around `I/O` and found `java.io.FileInputStream.getChannel()` on the internet. I want to know the exact purpose of `getChannel`. Why do we need to use `java.io.FileInputStream.getChannel()`?

Example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_getchannel.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating the [channel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html),The stream will be safe for access by multiple concurrent threads.

And from [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) class:

> File channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. The close method may be invoked at any time, as specified by the Channel interface. Only one operation that involves the channel's position or can change its file's size may be in progress at any given time; attempts to initiate a second such operation while the first is still in progress will block until the first operation completes. Other operations, in particular those that take an explicit position, may proceed concurrently; whether they in fact do so is dependent upon the underlying implementation and is therefore unspecified.

Comment: `The stream will be safe for access by multiple concurrent threads.` That make a sense...

Comment: No it doesn't. Creating the channel has no effect on thread safety. Answer is incorrect.

Comment: @EJP Vakh said but Suresh's answer make some sense. @Vakh explain bit more. If its low level utility then why `java` team created such a thing?

Comment: OK but that isn't the entire motivation for the existence of the API, it is? FileChannels also provide I/O via ByteBuffers; locks; memory mapped I/O; all the things listed by @Vakh. I don't agree it is a 'low-level' API.

Answer (score 2):

`getChannel` simply returns a `FileChannel` to the original `File`.

[FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) offers a way of reading, writing, mapping, and manipulating a file. It is quite a low level utility class and if you are new to Java, I would not recommend using this class but have a look at [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) or [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

Answer (score 0):

The **getChannel()**  method is also important when You want to acquire a **lock**
in a specific area of a file or even when You want to **Lock** the entire file.

```
public void blockFiles() throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("some.txt"));
    FileChannel fileChannel = fis.getChannel();
    try {
       FileLock fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();
        if (fileLock !=null){

            System.out.println("File is locked, You won't get access anymore");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is useful when You have multiple processes working on the same file and You want to prevent concurrency problems.